# Issue with postgres copy of very large CSV freezing Ubuntu

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm having issues populating postgres tables with a very large csv file (~40gb) using the COPY command. This is my first time really using SQL/postgres, but I have several years experience in R/python/linux.

```
CREATE DATABASE exampledb OWNER exampleuser;

#create schema
\c exampledb;
CREATE SCHEMA exampledbSC;
set search_path to exampledbSC;

#this creates the tables
psql 'dbname=exampledb user=exampleuser options=--search_path=exampledbSC' -f postgres_create_tables.sql

#this populates the tables with csv data 
psql 'dbname=exampledb user=exampleuser options=--search_path=exampledbSC' -f postgres_load_data.sql -v data_dir='/home/user/datafolder'
```

The inside of the last script has several \copy calls between the csvs and tables like so:

```
--  Load Data for Table table1
\copy table1 FROM 'table1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL ''
--  Load Data for Table table2
\copy table2 from 'table2.csv' delimiter ',' csv header NULL ''
```

The first 3 \copy execute fine, but the 4th is the 40gb file - eventually I loose control of my keyboard and clicking ability in Ubuntu (but can move mouse). I have left the program in this state for about ~8hours as the readme specifically states it could be a multi hour process, but this seems abnormal. I am on a local machine with 16 cores, 32gb RAM access data on a M.2 nvme drive.Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue had something to do with me running postgres-10, but the table building script being for previous versions. There was a second version 10 of the script I used that finished in under an hour.